# JSON.dump of a given object works in command line, not inside a script

Tags: python, json

```
object = {'score-set': [('SomeString', 1.0)], 'n': 10, 'num-found': 1, 'start': 0}
type(object) is dict.
```

When I do this in the command line 
json.dump(object,f)

where f is an writable open file. I get the dump in the file perfectly.

But inside a program in a context like this:

```
def JSONresponse(object,request,jsonIndent=None):
    r=HttpResponse(mimetype="application/json")
    callback1=request.GET["jsoncallback"] if "jsoncallback" in request.GET else None
    callback2=request.GET["callback"] if "callback" in request.GET else None
    callback = callback1 or callback2
    if callback and len(callback) > 1:
        r.write(callback + "(")
        json.dump(object,r,indent=jsonIndent)
        r.write(");")
    else:
        json.dump(object,r,indent=jsonIndent)
        r.write("\n")
    return r
```

I get the following exception on the json.dump line.

```
Exception Value: 1.0 is not JSON serializable
```

Any hints would be much appreciated,

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Just a style comment: you probably do not want to use `object` for your variable names since [`object`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#object) is a built-in function.

Comment: thanks for the tip, will change that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing your `float` isn't really a `float`, but acts like it in certain ways. Try converting it to a `float` before serializing it:

```
object['score-set'] = [(a, float(b)) for (a, b) in object['score-set']]
```

Comment: right on the money! I printed out the type of 1.0 and it turns out to be 'numpy.float32' <face palm>. Thanks again for your help!